# Lie algebra and category theory

Tags: category-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

This winter I have back to back an exam on introductory category theory (very basic, the biggest thing we did is the connection between (co-)products and adjoints) and an exam on Lie Algebras (up to classification, with no mention of Lie groups). Given that they are back to back I was wondering if anybody knew of fun exercises to practice both at the same time. A pdf or a particular exercise you have done, both work fine. Thanks a lot in advance. (something like finding the adjoint(s) if there are any to the forgetful functor from lie algebras to vector spaces)

Comment: Lie algebra cohomology connects both topics, for example. You can show that the invariant functor $F$ from the category of $U(L)$-modules (universal enveloping algebra $U(L)$) to the category of $K$-modules ($K$ is the field), given by $F(M)=M^L$ is left exact, and take the right derived functors of $F$ to define the cohomology: $H^n(L,M)=(R^nF)(M)$. For details see Weibel's book.